# Elasticsearch 7.1: Convert mongodb aggregation pipeline to elastic search query

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongodb-query, elasticsearch-aggregation, amazon-elasticsearch

This is my first time using elastic search so bear with me.
I have two schemas, Offers Schema and Offer Comment Schema, I need to search by offer title and have each offer result with its comments

**Offer Schema**:

```
{
    title: {
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true,
    }
}
```

In the above offer schema, there is no field to reference offer comments

**Offer Comment Schema**:

```
{
    offer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Offer',
      es_indexed: true,
    },
    comment: {
      type: String,
      es_indexed: true,
    }
}
```

In the above offer comment schema, offer field reference the offer which the comment belongs to.
The following aggregation pipeline is used to achive the desired output via mongodb driver.

**Mongodb aggregation pipeline done on offers collection**:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'offercomments',
      let: {
        id: '$_id',
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ['$offer', '$$id'],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            createdAt: -1,
          },
        },
        {
          $limit: 1,
        },
      ],
      as: 'comments',
    },
  },
];
```

here are some output samples from the aggregation pipeline

**Aggregation output sample**:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "title": "offer title sample",
    "comments": [
      {
        "_id": "_123",
        "offer": "123",
        "comment": "Hello there"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "456",
    "title": "offer title sample",
    "comments": [
      {
        "_id": "_456",
        "offer": "456",
        "comment": "Hello there"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```